# Linux g++ compiling

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm new to programming on linux, and compiling in the terminal. I have three files:

sql.h

```
#ifndef SQL_H
#define SQL_H

#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <string>

class sqlite{
    
private:
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3 *statement;
    
public:
    sqlite(const char* filename);
    void create_table();
};


#endif
```

sql.cpp

```
  #include "sql.h"
#include <iostream>

sqlite::sqlite(const char* filename){
    if((sqlite3_open_v2(filename, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK) //fájl létrehozása
        std::cout << "Database has been created successfully!" << std::endl;
    
    else{
        std::cout << "Oops, something went wrong, please try again!" << std::endl;  
    }
}   


void sqlite::create_table(/*const std::string &tableName, const std::string &columnNames*/){

    //std::string command = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + columnNames;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "CREATE TABLE a (a INTEGER, b INTEGER)", -1, &statement, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(db);

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "sql.h"
#include <string>
int main(){
    
    sqlite s = sqlite("database.db");
    s.create_table();
    return 0;
}
```

And if I try to compile it with the command `g++ -Wall -Werror main.cpp -lsqlite3 -o sqlite_program`, I got the errors:

```
/tmp/ccKtrrtg.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `sqlite::sqlite(char const*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `sqlite::create_table()'
```

This is the first time, I try to compile a cpp with a custom header. Maybe I should do that with a different command?

update: I've updated the code, it was buggy. :) Now it works!

Comment: The compiler is not magic, you have to tell it what you are trying to compile (or link, in this case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284720/undefined-reference-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have multiple input files, which will all form a single binary.

the usual way (which scales well for larger number of files) is to compile each source-file into a binary *object* file, and then link all the object files into the final binary.

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -o main.o -c main.cpp 
g++ -Wall -Werror -o sql.o  -c sql.cpp
g++               -o sqlite    main.o sql.o -lsqlite3
```

Comment: The second line gives me the errors:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqg8he8rcuf1736/show.txt?m

Comment: @erbal include <iostream> in your sql.cpp

Comment: @erbal, that's because your code is buggy; you must include <iostream> in sql.cpp, the type of the `statement` member should be `sqlite3_stmt` rather than `sqlite3` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Try to run this

```
g++ -Wall -Werror main.cpp sql.cpp -lsqlite3 -o sqlite
```

This will compile your sql.cpp file and link it to the executable.

Comment: (What you, erbal, were missing was the input file, sql.cpp, that contained the definition of the function it was looking for.)

Comment: I got this error with this: 

sql.cpp: In constructor ‘sqlite::sqlite(const char*)’:
sql.cpp:5:3: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
sql.cpp:5:61: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
sql.cpp:8:3: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
sql.cpp:8:67: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
sql.cpp: In member function ‘void sqlite::create_table()’:
....

Comment: In your sql.cpp file (or the header file), you need to use `#include <iostream>`, which has the definitions of `std::cout` and `std::endl`.