# Pure functions file with header file always resulting in undefined reference

Tags: c++, function, c++11, header, undefined-reference

I'm trying to create a general functions file for myself. I want to do it right so no #include .cpp but .h files. However I result in undefined references all the time. I reproduced it with the following three files:

**main.cpp :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    cout << addNumbers(5,6);
}
```

**functions.h :**

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

int addNumbers(int x,int y);

#endif
```

**functions.cpp :**

```
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int addNumbers(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

The files are all in one folder. I'm using Linux Mint, geany and c++11.
Compiling results in the following error:

> main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `addNumbers(int, int)'

Unfortunately I only found similar problems concerning classes online. I have come so far as to understand it is a linking  problem though I have no clue about that part of the compiling process. Adding the function to the .cpp before main() or after with prototyping works fine. This question [Undefined reference C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284720/undefined-reference-c) seems to be similar but I don't understand the answers.

My questions are:

1. How can I solve this? (I do not wish to wrap the functions in a class or add them to the main.cpp)
2. If possible an explanation as to what is going wrong here.
3. I am wondering if I could also call specific functions with the :: as I have seen it around but never used it because I don't know how it works.

Thank you

Comment: My guess is you're not compiling functions.cpp (or not linking to it), what command did you compile this with?

Comment: are you including functions.o when linking?

Comment: @Borgleader I'm just using the F9 so build in "build" command from geany. F8 so "compile works on all files

Comment: @jsantander see above and I don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how geany works, but the basic stages (on command line) are:

1. [Compile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) functions.cpp: `g++ -c functions.cpp`
2. Compile main.cpp: `g++ -c main.cpp`
3. [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) them into an executable: `g++ -o myprog functions.o main.o`

From geany manual, it seems that build works only for one-file programs (bold is mine):

> For compilable languages such as C and C++, the Build command will
>   link the **current source file's** equivalent object file into an
>   executable. If the object file does not exist, the source will be
>   compiled and linked in one step, producing just the executable binary.

and

> If you need complex settings for your build system, or several
>   different settings, then writing a Makefile and using the Make
>   commands is recommended; this will also make it easier for users to
>   build your software

The working makefile for the problem would be:

Makefile :

```
objects = main.o functions.o

AddingNumbersExe : $(objects)
    g++ -o AddingNumbersExe $(objects)

main.o : main.cpp functions.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

functions.o : functions.cpp functions.h
    g++ -c functions.cpp

.PHONY : clean
clean : 
   -rm AddingNumbersExe $(objects)
```

After creating this file, the "make" option (Ctrl + F9) in geany works.

So to handle your two-file programs you'll need a [Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) or a more powerful IDE.